# Show that $M^m + A = M^{m+1}$ with $M,A$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, mathematical-physics, matrix-equations

Let $M,A$ denote matrices with
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right),
~~~~
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$

> Show that $$M^m + A = M^{m+1}.$$

$~$

**Context:** I encountered this problem when trying to prove that $M^m = E_2 + mA$ (1) by induction (where $E_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Adding $A$ on both sides yields $M^m + A = E_2 + mA +A =E_2 + (m+1)A$. Equation (1) would follow if $M^m + A = M^{m+1}$.

Comment: Hint: Induction, using $MA=A$.

Comment: You may want to prove instead that $$M^m = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $MA=A$, we prove by induction.

When $m=0$, check that:

$$M^1=M^0+A$$

where $M^0=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=I.$

Now, if $M^{m+1}=M^m+A$ then multiply both sides by $M$, and you get $$M^{m+2}=M^{m+1}+MA=M^{m+1}+A$$

---

More generally, if $A^2=0$ and $M=I+A$ then $MA=A+A^2=A$ and you have again that $M^{m+1}=M^{m}+A$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, $M$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, so $(M-I)^2 = 0$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Since $A = M - I$, then
\begin{align*}
M^{m+1} - M^m - A  &= M^m(M-I) - (M-I) = (M^m - I)(M-I)\\
&= (M^{m-1} + M^{m-2} + \cdots + M + I)(M-I)^2 = 0
\end{align*}
so $M^{m+1} = M^m + A$.